# Shifting data to different columns and "flushing" them up to take up empty spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask, currently i have this set of data where I want to condense the data from column to rows.

I want to shift the data up matching their header So example those in row G12:J14 shift to row G3:J5 and those in row G6:J8 will shift to row O3:R5 and then I would want to delete the entire row 6:14

My initial idea was to cut and paste to their respective column first then shift them to the top but i have no idea what kind of function could I use, could I use delete rows and shift them up? However, I do have data below row 14 as well would they shift up as well cause i after that i would want to delete rows 6:14 which will also delete the data underneath that moved up

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim g As Range

    LstRw = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For x = 3 To LstRw
        
        If Not Cells(x, 6).Find("F1", Lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
     
    
        ElseIf Not Cells(x, 6).Find("B2", Lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x, 7), Cells(x, 10)).Cut _
                           Range(Cells(x, 11), Cells(x, 14))
    
        ElseIf Not Cells(x, 6).Find("C3", Lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x, 7), Cells(x, 10)).Cut _
                           Range(Cells(x, 15), Cells(x, 18))
    
        End If

    Next x

End Sub
```

[image: Data image]

Comment: How are you planning to group the first column if the power generated is not the same for the different codes?

Comment: as there are actually more data below of different powers, so i sorted based on power then ill work in that range of group with the same power

Comment: Will there ever be more than three day readings and three night readings?

Comment: Sorry i missed the comment but yes there actually would be more power data with their own respective b2 c3 f1 data

Comment: That would definitely require alterations in the code provided, as it only provides for a maximum of three day and three night readings per `b2/c3/f1`.  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put your results on a separate page (or in a different area of the same worksheet.

Instead of multiple calls to/from the worksheet, it would be much faster to

- read the data into a VBA array
- process it
- create a new array for the results
- write and format that back to some destination

I suggest creating a User Defined Object (Class) to hold the data for each iteration of the code, to make it easier to create a results array.

I think the code below is annotated well enough so you can figure out what's going on, but feel free to ask questions.

***Be sure to set a reference (see Tools/References) to Microsoft Scripting Runtime***

## Class Module

**Rename this module `cPower`**

```
Option Explicit
Private pPower As String
Private pCode As String
Private pposD As Long
Private pnegD As Long
Private pDMW As Long
Private pMW As Long
Private pDays As Collection
Private pNights As Collection


Public Property Get Power() As String
    Power = pPower
End Property
Public Property Let Power(Value As String)
    pPower = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Code() As String
    Code = pCode
End Property
Public Property Let Code(Value As String)
    pCode = Value
End Property

Public Property Get posD() As Long
    posD = pposD
End Property
Public Property Let posD(Value As Long)
    pposD = Value
End Property

Public Property Get negD() As Long
    negD = pnegD
End Property
Public Property Let negD(Value As Long)
    pnegD = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DMW() As Long
    DMW = pDMW
End Property
Public Property Let DMW(Value As Long)
    pDMW = Value
End Property

Public Property Get MW() As Long
    MW = pMW
End Property
Public Property Let MW(Value As Long)
    pMW = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Days() As Collection
    Set Days = pDays
End Property
Public Function addDays(Values() As Long)
    pDays.Add Values
End Function

Public Property Get Nights() As Collection
    Set Nights = pNights
End Property
Public Function addNights(Values() As Long)
    pNights.Add Values
End Function


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pDays = New Collection
    Set pNights = New Collection
End Sub
```

## Regular Module

```
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub Power()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc, vRes, V, W
    Dim cP As cPower, dP As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, sKey As String, L(3) As Long
    Dim R As Range
    
'Set source and results worksheets, ranges
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

On Error Resume Next
    Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add after:=wsSrc
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
            Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
        Case Is <> 0
            Debug.Print "Error: "; Err.Description, "Number: "; Err.Number
    End Select
On Error GoTo 0
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read source data into vba array
With wsSrc

'Find the start of the data = "Power"
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:="Power", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If R Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Table not on worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
                    
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(R.Row, R.Column), .Cells(.Rows.Count, R.Column).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=6)
    
End With

'collect the data
Set dP = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cP = New cPower
    With cP
        .Power = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Code = Split(vSrc(I, 2), " ")(0)
            sKey = .Code
        .posD = vSrc(I, 3)
        .negD = vSrc(I, 4)
        .DMW = vSrc(I, 5)
        .MW = vSrc(I, 6)
        
            L(0) = .posD
            L(1) = .negD
            L(2) = .DMW
            L(3) = .MW
                
        If Not dP.Exists(sKey) Then
            If Split(vSrc(I, 2), " ")(1) = "Day" Then
                .addDays L
            Else
                .addNights L
            End If
            dP.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=cP
        Else
                If Split(vSrc(I, 2), " ")(1) = "Day" Then
                dP(sKey).addDays L
            Else
                dP(sKey).addNights L
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next I

'Create Results Array
'Rows = 2 header rows plus six data rows
'Columns = dictionary.count *4 + 2
        
ReDim vRes(0 To 7, 1 To dP.Count * 4 + 2)

'Headers
vRes(1, 1) = "Power"
vRes(1, 2) = "Day/Night"
    
    J = 3
    For Each W In dP.Keys
        vRes(0, J) = W
        J = J + 4
    Next W
    
    'Store the measurements into an array
    'to be added to either the Days or Nights collection
    For J = 3 To UBound(vRes, 2) Step 4
        vRes(1, J) = "d"
        vRes(1, J + 1) = "-d"
        vRes(1, J + 2) = "dmw"
        vRes(1, J + 3) = "mw"
    Next J
    
'Day/Night Column
For I = 2 To 4
    vRes(I, 2) = "Day"
Next I
For I = 5 To 7
    vRes(I, 2) = "Night"
Next I
    
'populate
Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long
For Each V In dP.Keys
    I = 3
    Do Until vRes(0, I) = V
        I = I + 4
    Loop
    lCol = I
    
    I = 2
    For Each W In dP(V).Days
        For J = 0 To 3
            vRes(I, lCol + J) = W(J)
        Next J
        vRes(I, 1) = dP(V).Power
        I = I + 1
    Next W
    I = 5
    For Each W In dP(V).Nights
        For J = 0 To 3
            vRes(I, lCol + J) = W(J)
        Next J
        vRes(I, 1) = dP(V).Power
        I = I + 1
    Next W
Next V

'Write the results
'Format the output
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(2)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Style = "Output" 'Note: This may not be internationally applicable
    .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 255
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    With Range(.Columns(3), Columns(UBound(vRes, 2)))
        .ColumnWidth = 5
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    
    For J = 3 To UBound(vRes, 2) Step 4
        Set R = Range(.Columns(J), .Columns(J + 3))
        With R
            .BorderAround Weight:=xlThick
            Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 4)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        End With
    Next J
    
End With

End Sub
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

***Note:** This will need to be modified if, **unlike** your example, you have multiple sets with different powers that need to be treated differently*

Comment: Hello! Personally i think your code is what i am looking for however, i am not familiar with class modules thus i think ill need to slowly digest and understand the code 1 by 1

Comment: @JingXuanSee See the late Chip Pearson's article: [Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx) for an excellent introduction.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @JingXuanSee Let me know if you need assistance modifying the code to handle multiple powers, and varying numbers of Days and Nights per power.